# Rhythmbox add entire library to a playlist

Tags: rhythmbox

I store all my music folder-wise. Today I imported everything into Rhythmbox, but am not sure how I can add all the tracks to a single playlist. Currently everything is in the Music tab and there's no option for right click. I also tried dragging a track onto a newly created playlist but it's not working, either.

[image]

Comment: The view you have means that you have not yet imported any tracks.  Highlight all the tracks and click "Import x selected tracks" to import those tracks.  You should then be able to right-click and display a menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The view you have means that you have not yet imported any tracks.

To resolve this:

- First highlight all the tracks
- Click "Import x selected tracks" to import those tracks.
- You should then be able to right-click and display a menu.
- From the right-click menu you can highlight all tracks and add to a playlist.

Answer (score 0):

Another way -

1. Create a new playlist.
2. Right-click edit the new playlist.
3. Select 'Path' in first dropdown
4. Select 'Starts with' in second dropdown.
5. Write 'file:///home/Music/folder' in textbox. (folder path may vary)
6. Click close.